# Create new layer in QGIS using SQL query

Tags: qgis, sql

This is a related question to: [Speed up performance of virtual layer based on GeoPackages in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/467088/speed-up-performance-of-virtual-layer-based-on-geopackages-in-qgis)

In that question, I was trying to use a virtual layer in QGIS (3.30) to add a region field to a suburb layer, by locating the centroid of the suburb within a region. The virtual layer was taking a ridiculously long time to create.

One of the comments to the question included: **"That being said, since the boundaries are unlikely to change, I wouldn't bother using a virtual layer".**

So the question is: **Is there a straightforward way of creating a new layer in QGIS using an SQL query, that doesn't involve a virtual layer.** Obviously, not being a virtual layer, the query would only run once on creation - which would be fine for this particular use.

[image]

Both the suburb layer and the region layer are of polygon type, in GeoPackage format, with a spatial index added using Vector->Create Spatial Index... I confirmed that the spatial indexes existed, using ogrinfo eg: `ogrinfo -sql "SELECT HasSpatialIndex('suburbs', 'geom')" suburbs.gpkg`

The suburb layer has around 4500 records, the region layer has 100 records.

SQL query is as follows - the region details/geometries are in the layer ABSStatisticalAreasLevel3_ :

```
select s.*, l3.SA3_NAME11
from Suburbs_ s 
join ABSStatisticalAreasLevel3_ l3 on ST_CONTAINS(l3.geometry, ST_CENTROID(s.geometry))
```

Comment: It looks like you could do it with the GDAL tool `Execute SQL` using the sqlite dialect, maybe

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [GDAL Execute SQL](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectormiscellaneous.html#gdalexecutesql) tool. My test data is different (ABS SA3 and SAL 2021), but the SQL statement I used is otherwise the same as yours.  Both input sal and sa3 layers are in a geopackage. I used the `-nln` parameter to specify the new layer name.

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT: If your layers are in separate gpkgs, you need to tell the sqlite driver to [attach](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) the other files using the [`PRELUDE_STATEMENTS` open option](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/sqlite.html#dataset-open-options):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. However I couldn't get it to work as my two layers were in two separate GeoPackages, and the interface didn't seem to allow for more than one input file? Is that possible? I have managed to get it to work using the native Execute SQL tool, which I'll write up as a separate answer.

Comment: @TomBrennan you can attach the other gpkg, see edit

Answer (score 2):

You can use the native [Execute SQL](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#execute-sql) tool under Vector General in the Processing Toolbox.

The main advantage of this tool over the **GDAL Execute SQL** tool is that the native SQL can use the layers as named in the Layers panel - so the same SQL will work as for the Virtual Layers tool.

[image]

[image]

Timewise, it took around 12-15 minutes to run - comparable to the Virtual Layer time - but obviously a one-off cost.

Note that as per [Speed up performance of virtual layer based on GeoPackages in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/467088/speed-up-performance-of-virtual-layer-based-on-geopackages-in-qgis/467862#467862), you can add a `_search_frame_` clause to the SQL and this will create the layer in around 60s (as opposed to 12 minutes+).

```
select s.*, l3.SA3_NAME11
from Suburbs_ s 
join ABSStatisticalAreasLevel3_ l3 on ST_CONTAINS(l3.geometry, ST_CENTROID(s.geometry))
where s._search_frame_ = l3.geometry
```